# Why is not the doGet trigger function able to access parameters passed in the request?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, web-applications, scope

I am trying to write a leave request system and have copied code from other examples in order to get where I am.

The largest problem I am having is the `doGet` seems not to be able to read the parameters. If I plug the parameters into the code, it works fine, but when I try to pass the variables with https link it doesn't work. Any ideas?

I have published it as a web App and given anyone in my domain access to it.

Here is the https link: `https://script.google.com/a/olemissalumni.com/macros/s/mywebappURL/exec?id=2_ABaOnue6Zr2ADAQPNUo-NdwmIgOL-J4Gk9H6ihNVkqZwLs2ubWh_0SaXYdllDpb_1r6AyCA&status=Approved`

Here is the `doGet` trigger function.

```
function doGet(e) {

  //testing variables

  //  var responseID = '2_ABaOnue6Zr2ADAQPNUo-NdwmIgOL-J4Gk9H6ihNVkqZwLs2ubWh_0SaXYdllDpb_1r6AyCA';
  //  var status = 'Approved';


  // Retrieve the parameter information for response ID and status
  var responseID = e.parameters.id;
  var status = e.parameters.status;

  // Open the sheet which stores the responses
  var ssID = 'spreadsheet id' // Replace with spreadsheet ID
  var ssName = 'Form Responses' // Replace with sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName(ssName);

  // Find the row where the ID in the URL equals the ID in the sheet and update the
  // status to the parameter value
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log('Email' + data[1][1]);
  Logger.log('type' + data[1][9]);
  //console.log(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][11] == responseID) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 12, 1, 1).setValue(status);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][0], "GMT+0200", "EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
      var type = data[i][10];
      var email = data[i][1]; //get the actual email address of the person who filled out the e
      sheet.getRange(i, 13, 1, 1).setValue(email);
    }
  }

  if (status == 'Approved') {
    var subject = 'Your e for time-off has been approved';
    var message = 'Your e for time-off (' + type + ') on ' + date + ' has been approved.';

  } else {
    var subject = 'Your e for time-off has been denied';
    var message = 'Your e for time-off (' + type + ') on ' + date + ' has been denied.';
  }

  // Send email to employee alerting them of the approval/denial of e
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

  // Show message to manager that the response has been updated.
  var result = "The e has been '" + status + "'.";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);

}
```

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: **Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.**

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for scripts that cannot be run without external dependencies or platforms. Use proper code formatting [Ctrl+K] instead: single backticks (“`”) for one-liners, property names and methods, code fences (“````”) for code blocks. Also please avoid chit-chat in questions, SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A website.

Comment: Re:your issue - be careful as `parameters` contains your parameters encapsulated in an Array. Given your code snippet and the fact that you do not destructure the array, you would want to use `parameter` instead

Comment: I am tempted to close as duplicate of an answer about `e.paramater` and `e.parameters`, but not sure if that all to it. Could you please show how do you pass the query parameters to the url - just in case?

Comment: @TheMaster - oups, I apologize for linking the sample, got confused by the "here is the link". My previous comment can be disregarded, I tend to forget that the non-strict comparison will work in such case `["a"] == "a"`. Hm, inthewoods71, if you log the `e` event object, what is logged (don't forget to redeploy after adding the code)?

Answer (score 1):

### Your WebApp accesses the parameters correctly, the error source is different

- While in general for retrieving strings opposed to arrays, you should use `e.parameter` instead of `e.parameters`, in your case Apps Script will convert the array to a string for you, so that the comparison of type `if (['Approved'] == 'Approved')`  will return `true`
- However, in general be careful with comparing values to arrays and use `e.parameter` instead of `e.parameters` for accessing single values
- Now the real problem of your code is that  `MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);` is outside of the `for` loop
- Within the `for` loop and inner `if` statement you overwrite the value of `email` (and `date` and `type`) and send the email after exiting the loop to the last saved email
- This will lead to problems if

- `data[i][11] == responseID` statement is fulfilled more than once
- If there is no valid email address in `data[i][1]`
- If the `if` condition is never fulfilled
- In the latter case  the variable `email` does not exist, but the script still tries to send an email and errors

**Solution:**

- Move the email sending funciton into the `if` statement
- Also, incorporate logs throughoout the code to make sure that your retrieve the correct data (in one line you define `Logger.log('type' + data[1][9]);` and later: `var type = data[i][10];`
- Make sure that you deploy your WebApp as a new version after incorporating the changes.

Sample:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  
  //testing variables
  
  //  var responseID = '2_ABaOnue6Zr2ADAQPNUo-NdwmIgOL-J4Gk9H6ihNVkqZwLs2ubWh_0SaXYdllDpb_1r6AyCA';
  //  var status = 'Approved';
  
  
  // Retrieve the parameter information for response ID and status
  var responseID = e.parameter.id;
  var status = e.parameter.status;
  
  // Open the sheet which stores the responses
  var ssID = 'spreadsheet id' // Replace with spreadsheet ID
  var ssName = 'Form Responses' // Replace with sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()//.openById(ssID).getSheetByName(ssName);
  
  // Find the row where the ID in the URL equals the ID in the sheet and update the
  // status to the parameter value
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log('Email' + data[1][1]);
  Logger.log('type' + data[1][9]);
  //console.log(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][11] == responseID) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 12, 1, 1).setValue(status);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][0], "GMT+0200", "EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
      // 9 or 10???!!!
      var type = data[i][10];
      var email = data[i][1]; //get the actual email address of the person who filled out the e
      sheet.getRange(i, 13, 1, 1).setValue(email);      
      if (status == 'Approved') {
        var subject = 'Your e for time-off has been approved';
        var message = 'Your e for time-off (' + type + ') on ' + date + ' has been approved.';
        
      } else {
        var subject = 'Your e for time-off has been denied';
        var message = 'Your e for time-off (' + type + ') on ' + date + ' has been denied.';
      }
      
      // Send email to employee alerting them of the approval/denial of e
      Logger.log("email will be sent");
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
  }
  
  // Show message to manager that the response has been updated.
  var result = "The e has been '" + status + "'.";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);  
}
```